FME 2023.1.2 Forgot to check overwrite option as a result the data is duplicate
I wanted to convert my geodatabase into a geopackage using FME. I wanted to overwrite my data unfortunately I forgot to tick the overwrite option. As a result all my data are duplicate. Is there any option I can use to undo my action. Or do I need to delete everything in the geopackage then upload again?
Thanks,
I am new to FME. I found an option called Clear Values. But I am not sure if it going to affect our online data. Or I might create another geopackage then upload the data.
